# Change floors on google maps street layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm using `Web > OpenLayers plugin > Google Maps > Google Street` to pull in the floorplan a user submitted to Google on a building.  I'm using it to trace my own shapefile.  But, it only shows the first floor.  On Google Maps web application, you can change the floor when you have the building selected, is there an option to do this in QGIS?

Comment: it seems to me, that the floorplan is provided as soon as you click somewhere in the building google have a floor plan of. You can also see, that the URL is changing when you click on the floor plan and  also when on clicking different floors. Therefore I think it will be hard to get those data with the plugin